# Using emacs org-mode, how to publish the unchanged files in a project?

Tags: emacs, publish, org-mode

I am running Emacs 24.3 and org-mode 8.25f. When I use **M-x org-publish** command, the org-mode only convert the new .org files to .html and skip all the others which have not been modified since last publish operation.

However, usually I have some changes in the publish setup and some CSS code changes. I want them to take effect to all the files, not just the recently modified ones.

So, can I tell org-mode not to skip these unchanged files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should work:

```
M-: (org-publish "project name" t)
```

This runs `org-publish` with `FORCE` set to `t`. From the docs:

```
When optional argument FORCE is non-nil, force publishing all
files in PROJECT.  With a non-nil optional argument ASYNC,
publishing will be done asynchronously, in another process.
```

As [you discovered yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258769/using-emacs-org-mode-how-to-publish-the-unchanged-files-in-a-project/21259718?noredirect=1#comment32032683_21259718), a [prefix argument will also force Org to publish all files](http://orgmode.org/guide/Publishing.html#Publishing):

```
C-u M-x org-publish
```

Comment: how to add this functionality to config file?

Comment: What do you mean by "add this functionality to config file"? You want to make this the default when you run `org-publish`?

Comment: yes, I just make my own function, but maybe it can be simpler that that.

Comment: That's probably best.

Answer (score 0):

The export dispatcher, which you can summon with `C-c C-e` in the Org mode, provides the relevant "Force publishing" option under `C-f`.  Thus, to force-publish the current file, type `C-c C-e C-f P f`.